# Seaborn Catplot: Show line plot

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

The catplot function has an option called kind. It allows me to specify 'bar', 'point' etc. I am looking for a line plot. I am using  catplot to show two categories side by side, using the same time scale,plotting sales from two different products. The goal is to show the two trends side by side.

Comment: Use `kind="point"` to get a categorical line plot (with points). Else, don't use catplot at all, but just a normal lineplot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`catplot`, as the name implies, is meant to be used by categorical data (ie data where 2 or more categories would be shown on the x-axis), not continuous data (such as a time series in your case).

I think you are looking for [`sns.relplot()` with `kind='line'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot)